# Why do all links on my Wordpress site show me the homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I click on any link on my Wordpress site it loads homepage, but link URL changes on the address bar?

What could be wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, changes made to the .htaccess file can cause WordPress to redirect all links back to the home page instead of showing the page requested.
In those cases, you need to reset the permalinks within WordPress will resolve this issue and for that.

1. Go to **Settings** > **Permalinks**.
2. Make note of the current setting.(If you are using a custom structure, copy or save the custom structure somewhere.)
3. Select the **Default** option.
4. Click **Save** Changes.
5. Now select the previous setting you had before **Default** was selected.
6. Click **Save** Changes.

If you are getting **404 Not Found errors** when you click on links in WordPress, then some code may be missing from the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this means that some template files of your theme are missing and default `index.php` is loaded instead. See '[Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)'. Be sure to  have a proper template file for the page/archive you are viewing. For example, you need a `single.php` or `singular.php` template to display a single post page and a `category.php` or `archive.php` to display a category page.

Another possible reason is wrong configuration of your site permalinks structure (Settings -> Permalinks) or wrong `.htaccess` file. Or some confilcts of `rewrite` parameters when registering custom post types/taxonomies.

Your question is too common to find out the exact reason.